# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Bottle' to data type int

Tags: sql

This is my question: Select all rows from the ProductVendor Table and only the corresponding data from the Unit of Measure table.  Display columns BusinessEntityID, ProductID, StandardPrice from the Product Vendor table and the Name from the Unit of Measure table.  Write this 2 different ways – 1 using a join and the other using a WHERE clause. (10 Pts.)

This is my code:

```
 USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
    SELECT  CAST(Name as INT),BusinessEntityID, ProductID, StandardPrice, Name
    FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor Right Outer JOIN Production.UnitMeasure
    ON Purchasing.ProductVendor.BusinessEntityID = Production.UnitMeasure.Name
```

And I keep getting this error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Bottle' to data type int.

Comment: why are you casting `Name` as an `Int`?

Comment: `SELECT 42 AS Name, ...`

Comment: Well because I have to convert from one data type to another so should I use Convert(int,Name)?

Comment: @Amanda Necessary: what number the `Bottle` is assumed to be?

Comment: "because I have to convert from one data type to another" -- it doesn't explain the original intention. Why do you need to convert to an incompatible type?

Comment: "10 Pts." --- is it a homework actually? If so then "This is my question" --- it's not your question, but it's your assignment.

Comment: I don't need to that was the error that I kept getting so when I looked it up it told me to convert. So that is what I did

Comment: So you're doing some random things without understanding what they are for and expect that eventually it will lead you to the desired results? It never happens in a realworldland.

Comment: So what if it's homework, many of the people are getting paid off the free help they receive on SO. OP made an attempt, and asked a specific question regarding that attempt, seems good to me.

Comment: @Goat CO: it's not a "specific question", it's an assignment copied as-is (even with points amount they will get for solving it). Don't you see the difference?

Comment: @zerkms Except that there's also the query tried, and the error given.  OP didn't say "what's the query to do this?"

Comment: @Goat CO: yep, there is some random query indeed. Well, you see it as an "attempt", I see it as a job delegation.

Comment: @zerkms imo it's better than many questions that get answered, it's no big secret that people react negatively to homework questions here, but I'd rather help a student than someone who gets paid to have SO do their work for them.

Comment: @Goat CO: how will it be helpful to a student? They don't understand basic things. So they need to read the book/lectures once and over again. That's how it's supposed to be if you're a student.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your `JOIN`, as `BusinessEntityID` is an INT, while `Name` is an `NVARCHAR`, when you `JOIN` on those two fields it's attempting to convert the `Name` field to an `INT`, which fails as it doesn't contain `INT` values.

You need to change the `ON` criteria to be the appropriate fields that relate the two tables (and use table aliases to make it simple):

```
SELECT pv.BusinessEntityID, pv.ProductID, pv.StandardPrice, m.Name
FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor pv
JOIN Production.UnitMeasure m
   ON  pv.BusinessEntityID = m.ID --?
```

Comment: How common is it for a "specific question" to not provide the schema description so you should guess the matching columns? :-)